# Нужна ли запятая после слова "возможно"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

**Возможно у вас есть ещё вопросы, с которыми я могла бы вам помочь?**

Comment: Стилистически странная фраза. Спрашивая "У вас есть вопросы?", подразумевaют  вопросы, которые еще не были заданы, а не проблемы, с которыми можно помочь.

Comment: Корректно выглядела бы фраза:  **Возможно, есть ещё вопросы, с которыми я могла бы вам помочь?**

Answer (score 1):

[**ВОЗМОЖНО**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/148015)
**I** *наречие качеств.-обстоят.*
Насколько можно (обычно с формами сравнительной степени прилагательных).
*Пожалуйста, сделайте это возможно быстрее.*

**II** *предикатив*
 1. О представляющейся возможной, допустимой, осуществимой ситуации.
 *Вполне возможно, что это произойдёт.*

**2.** Употребляется как **вводное слово**, соответствующее по значению: **может быть, вероятно.**
*Когда-нибудь эти чудеса техники, возможно, перейдут в серийное производство.*

В Вашем предложении *возможно* — это вводное слово, после которого ставится запятая. Вводное слово *возможно* используется тогда, когда Вы хотите указать на вероятность какого-либо действия, состояния, явления:

*Возможно, женщина сможет победить на уровне выборов губернского масштаба.*
**Возможно, у вас есть ещё вопросы, с которыми я могла бы вам помочь?**

Comment: А это правило, не относится к моему предложению?  "Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения"

Comment: Нет, это правило Вашего предложения не касается, т. к. вводное слово стоит **в начале** предложения, а не внутри него (никаких вторых "опускаемых" запятых здесь нет). Думаю, Вы имели в виду классический пример: _Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой_ (Пауст.).

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется. "Возможно" - это вводное слово в начале предложения.

*Возможно, у вас есть ещё вопросы, с которыми я могла бы вам помочь?*

---

**[ВОЗМОЖНО, *вводное слово*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_295)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]